# Warning: touch(): Utime failed: No error in <PATH>wp-includes\nav-menu.php Wordpress on migration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a working wordpress site in live. When I try to download and configure in my local machine(windows with XAMPP), it throwing a weird error.

If I do "echo" anything in "index.php" of the wordpress file and run the website, it throws a following error

```
Warning: touch(): Utime failed: No error in <PATH_OF_DIRECTORY>\wp-includes\nav-menu.php on line 560
```

And automatically the index.php file changed to read only.

If I not edit anything in index.php file and run, it not changing to read only. Only I edit the file, it changed to readonly.

I found the solution in online and tried to add the `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in config file. But no improvements.

Any idea to resolve this issue??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this myself, accidentally set `chmod($filename, 06444)` instead of `chmod($filename, 0644)`, leaving PHP unable to run `touch()`